# Solving a System of Equations Closed Forms

Tags: equation-solving

I am relatively new to mathematica and I do not know how to get the closed form from the system of equations. I have 7 equations with 7 unknowns:

$c_{*},\omega_{*},h_{*}, P_{*}, g_{*}, Q_*, L_{Y_{*}}$

The system of equations is given by:

\begin{align}
       g_{*}  & = (1-\theta) \alpha Q_{*}^{\gamma} P_{*}^{(1-\alpha)\epsilon} h_{*}^{(1-\alpha)}L_{Y_{*}}^{\beta} - \rho - \mu (\rho + \mu) \frac{1}{c_{*}} \\
g_{*} &= \delta (\bar{L}-L_{Y_{*}}) \\
     g_{*} & = Q_{*}^{\gamma} P_{*}^{(1-\alpha)\epsilon} (h_{*})^{1-\alpha} - c_{*}-m P_{*}^{\epsilon}h_{*}   \\
    P_{*} &= bQ_{*}(1-Q_{*})\\
(1-\theta) \beta  [Q_{*}^{\gamma} (P_{*}^{\epsilon}h_{*})^{1-\alpha}L_{Y_{*}}^{\beta}] & = \omega_{*} L_{Y_{*}}\\
 (1-\theta)(1-\alpha) \epsilon [A(Q_{*}) (P_{*}^{\epsilon}h_{*})^{1-\alpha}L_{Y_{*}}^{\beta}] & = \tau_{*} P_{*} + m\epsilon h_{*} P_{*}^{\epsilon}\\
 g_{*} & = \frac{\delta \big[ 1- (1-\theta)(\alpha+\beta) - (1-\theta)(1-\alpha)\epsilon \big]}{(1-\theta)\beta}L_{Y_{*}} - \frac{\delta m h_{*}\hat{P}_{*}^{\epsilon}}{\omega_{*}}
\end{align}

where $\theta, \alpha,\gamma,\epsilon,\beta,\rho,\mu,\delta,\bar{L}, b, \tau_{*}, m$ are all positive real parameters.

I would like to get the closed forms that derive from this system of equations, is that doable? If so how should I do it?  I wish to get the closed forms without assigning a numerical value to the parameters.

Do you recommend any book for a Mathematica beginner?

---

I started with Solve, but now I am not able to proceed.

```
f[g_, l_, P_, c_, h_, Q_, w_] = 
 Solve[{ g == (1 - \[Theta]) \[Alpha]  Q^\[Gamma] P^((1 - \[Alpha]) \
\[Epsilon]) h^(1 - \[Alpha]) l^\[Beta] - \[Rho] - \[Mu] (\[Rho] + \
\[Mu])/c, g == \[Delta] (\[CapitalAlpha] - l), 
   g ==  Q^\[Gamma] P^((1 - \[Alpha]) \[Epsilon]) h^(1 - \[Alpha]) - 
     c - \[CapitalMu] P^\[Epsilon] h, 
   P == b Q (1 - 
       Q), (1 - \[Theta]) (1 - \[Alpha]) \[Epsilon] Q^\[Gamma] P^\
\[Epsilon] h^(1 - \[Alpha])
     l^\[Beta] == \[Tau] P + \[CapitalMu] \[Epsilon] h P^\[Epsilon] , \
\[Theta] > 0, \[Alpha] > 0, \[Gamma] > 0, \[Epsilon] > 0, \[Rho] > 
    0, \[Mu] > 0, \[Beta] > 0, \[CapitalAlpha] > 0, \[Tau] > 
    0, \[CapitalMu] > 0, \[Delta] > 0}, {g, Q, P, h, c, l, w}]
```

Note that I just wrote 5 of the 7 equations as a tryout.

Comment: i recommend Paul Wellin - Programming with Mathematica®_ An Introduction-Cambridge University Press (2013)

Comment: In principle, it is possible, if this system is mathematically solvable. To understand how to operate I recommend first of all to have a look at Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/Solve and go through all examples that you find there. After that, maybe, you will already have a good answer to your question.

Comment: @ Ricardo de la Fuente what it means by this in equations !? [ argument ]
Clarify the math problem plz

Comment: The parenthesis and brackets are just multiplications.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I have already confirmed that the model is solvable! Should I thus use the Solve function?

Comment: yes use solve friend

Comment: @Alrubaie Could you please tell me what is wrong with the code below?

Comment: please add your answer (or code) as part of your question.

Comment: This is likely to be impossible given that several exponents are parameters.

Comment: Now, after you published the code, it is clear what is it all about. Your equation is highly nonlinear. Typically, such equations only have closed analytical solutions in exceptional cases. The fact that some powers may be nonintegers makes it even worse. I would not expect Mma to give a closed analytical solution. As a minor comment to your code: Solve does not admit inequalities. However, after removing inequalities Mma on my machine cannot find the solution.